# Detecting reason for failure to open an ofstream when fail() is true

Tags: c++, iostream

Seems like this should be simple, but I don't find it in a net search.

I have an ofstream which is `open()`, and `fail()` is now true. I'd like to know the reason for the failure to open, like with `errno` I would do `sys_errlist[errno]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no standard way of finding out exactly why open() failed. Note that sys_errlist is not standard C++ (or Standard C, I believe).

Answer (score 19):

The [strerror](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/string/strerror) function from `<cstring>` might be useful.  This isn't necessarily standard or portable, but it works okay for me using GCC on an Ubuntu box:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
#include <fstream>
using std::ofstream;
#include <cstring>
using std::strerror;
#include <cerrno>

int main() {

  ofstream fout("read-only.txt");  // file exists and is read-only
  if( !fout ) {
    cout << strerror(errno) << '\n'; // displays "Permission denied"
  }

}
```

Comment: That might well work, and strerror() is a standard C++ function. Unfortunately, the standard does not state that open() sets errno, so you can't absolutely depend on it.

Answer (score 2):

This is portable but doesn't appear to give useful info:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <fstream>
using std::ofstream;

int main(int, char**)
{
    ofstream fout;
    try
    {
        fout.exceptions(ofstream::failbit | ofstream::badbit);
        fout.open("read-only.txt");
        fout.exceptions(std::ofstream::goodbit);
        // successful open
    }
    catch(ofstream::failure const &ex)
    {
        // failed open
        cout << ex.what() << endl; // displays "basic_ios::clear"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

- `GetLastError()` to get error code.
- `FormatSystemMessage(GetLastError())` to get error message.

Answer (score -4):

we need not use std::fstream, we use boost::iostream

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

void main()
{
   namespace io = boost::iostreams;

   //step1. open a file, and check error.
   int handle = fileno(stdin); //I'm lazy,so...

   //step2. create stardard conformance streem
   io::stream<io::file_descriptor_source> s( io::file_descriptor_source(handle) );

   //step3. use good facilities as you will
   char buff[32];
   s.getline( buff, 32);

   int i=0;
   s >> i;

   s.read(buff,32);

}
```

Comment: So what will this display on failure?