# Program crashes after opening file

Tags: c++, ifstream

I need to read values from a file into my program. The file is opening successfully, but then it crashes right away. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
void createList(intNode*& intList)
{
    intNode* lastInt; //points to last integer in file
    lastInt = NULL;
    int fileInt; //int read from input file
    ifstream intInputFile;

    intInputFile.open("intInput.txt");
    if (intInputFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "intInput.txt open successful" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "intInput.txt open unsuccessful" << endl;
    }
    intInputFile >> fileInt;
    while(!intInputFile.eof())
    {
        intNode* anotherInt;
        anotherInt = new intNode;
        if(intList==NULL)
        {
            intList = anotherInt;
            lastInt = anotherInt;
        }
        else
        {
            lastInt->nextNode = anotherInt;
        }
        lastInt = lastInt->nextNode;
        lastInt->intValue = fileInt;
        lastInt->nextNode = NULL;
        intInputFile >> fileInt;
    }
    intInputFile.close();
    cout << "List created from input file" << endl;
}
```

Thanks.

Edit:

After checking, I have a problem right after

```
else
    {
        lastInt->nextNode = anotherInt;
    }
```

So there must be a problem with this code:

```
    lastInt = lastInt->nextNode;
    lastInt->intValue = fileInt;
    lastInt->nextNode = NULL;
    intInputFile >> fileInt;
```

Because I had a cout statement directly after it and it didn't work.

And after looking into it more, the problem is with this line:

```
     intInputFile >> fileInt;
```

Comment: Can you add more cout to find where the code crashes exactly ?

Comment: If it's crashing, then yes, there's something wrong with your program.

Comment: Okay, I will try that now.

Comment: What are you going to try now?

Comment: @ScottHunter What Josay recommended.

Comment: Can we see your constructor for intNode, because if you aren't initialising nextNode to NULL then you have a problem with this: lastInt = lastInt->nextNode;

Comment: My advice. Use gdb to get a stack trace and debug your way through the code.

Comment: @DavidSaxon Not sure what you mean, can you please explain?

Comment: I added more cout statements in between, and here is the problem: intInputFile >> fileInt;

Comment: The above statement is supposed to read the next integer from the file into fileInt. Does this mean there is something wrong with my original file?

Comment: @AA did you write intNode yourself or is it from another library? If you wrote it yourself what does the constructor for intNode look like?

Comment: @DavidSaxon intNode is a struct containing an integer and a pointer which points to an instance of intNode. This is a linked list program.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `intList` isn't `NULL`, then you'll call `lastInt->nextNode = anotherInt;` during your first iteration of the loop while `lastInt` is still `NULL` causing the program to crash (due to it following a null pointer).

Comment: My program is crashing due because of the statement:        intInputFile >>fileInt;

Comment: That doesn't match your edited post "I have a problem right after". You should edit your question. Also try to set a break point at that line and verify your stream is fine when reaching it.

Comment: Okay I did. I know everything is okay beforehand, I think the problem is from my original file of values. I made a file with 5 integers, and when my program tries to read the next integer it crashes. I put each integer value in my file on a separate line, is that okay?

Comment: Not sure I understood you right, but this should work anyway: If the input isn't valid, the value would be set to `0` and the program would still continue - it wouldn't crash. There's most likely something wrong with the stream.

Comment: Oh okay, I'm new to this, so what do you mean by something wrong with the stream?

Comment: I have changed the area you spoke of:else
       {

          lastInt->nextNode = new intNode;
          lastInt = lastInt->nextNode;
          lastInt->nextNode = NULL;
       }

Comment: But now my program runs uncontrollably...

Comment: "Wrong" as in "you somehow destroyed or screwed up a part of the `istream` object. It shouldn't crash by itself, even if the data is wrong. Your new code won't fix the problem, `lastInt` is still undefined/`NULL` at the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `intInput.txt` file is formatted properly, your `intInputFile >> fileInt;` line should read the first integer from it just fine, so there must be some problem with the `ifstream`. The `is_open` member function of `ifstream` only tells you whether the stream has a file associated with it. It doesn't necessarily tell you if there was a problem opening the file. You can check for that with the `good` function. E.g.:

```
if (intInputFile.good()) 
    cout << "intInputFile is good" << endl;
else 
    cout << "intInputFile is not good" << endl;
```

Depending on your system, you may be able to find out the cause of any error using `strerror(errno)` as follows:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>

...

if (!intInputFile.good())
    cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
```

This works for me, but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960541/detecting-reason-for-failure-to-open-an-ofstream-when-fail-is-true) for more information as it may not work everywhere.