# Filestreams won't open

Tags: c++, c++11, ofstream

I have the following C++ code as part of a larger program:

```
/* Open the output streams */
    std::ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open(outputName);
    std::ofstream outputFile1;
    outputFile1.open(outputName1);
    std::ofstream outputFile2;
    outputFile2.open(outputName2);

    std::cout <<  outputFile.is_open() << " " << outputFile1.is_open() << " " << outputFile2.is_open() << std::endl;
if (inputFile.is_open() && outputFile.is_open() && outputFile1.is_open() && 

outputFile2.is_open())
...
```

It's supposed to open several output file streams which will then - if they are all open - do a series of operations which writes to each one. However the program terminates early because the streams are never open:

```
0 0 0
Filestream or output streams could not open, ending program!
```

The variables outputName are std::strings, which I thought was allowed in C++11 (I have the -std flag enabled for C++11 in my OpenBlocks compiler options).

I'm not sure why the streams won't open.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the file names?

Comment: How are we supposed to know why you can't access those files?!

Comment: _"The variables outputName are std::strings, which I thought was allowed in C++11"_ It is, and if that were the problem then you'd see a compilation error.

Comment: Apologies, I should add - the output files are not already extant - I expect the program to create them and then write to them, I was under the impression if a name used to open an ofstream does not correspond to an already existing file, a file of that name would be created. The name I'm using is simply "testout1.txt" "testout2.txt" and "testout3.txt". I (maybe incorrectly) assume that those files would be made in the current directory where I ran the executable.

Comment: Just used 'if( !outputFile ) {
    std::cout << strerror(errno) << '\n';
  }' in my code with the cerrno library and it says: No such file or directory!

Answer (score 6):

File streams could fail to open for a number of reasons, such as if the path is invalid, if access is denied, or if the file is already open for writing in another program.

These errors are OS-dependent, and thus there is no standard way of reporting which one occured. However, you may be able to obtain an error code with the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960541/detecting-reason-for-failure-to-open-an-ofstream-when-fail-is-true).

If you're using Windows, be careful; if reports error code 5 (access denied) for all sorts of reasons that have nothing to do with permissions.